# I can't print the bibliography in Texshop

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, texshop

I see that there have been similar questions in the past, but nome of them work for me.
I am utilising Texshop, and I want to print the bibliography at the end. I created a very simple bibliography with Bibdesk of one element. The code is very simple

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{check.bib}
\begin{document}
ciao

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I also tried changing the backend to Biber but nothing changes at all.
I get the following error message:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./check.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-bibtex.def

Package biblatex Warning: Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend:
(biblatex)                functionality may be reduced/unavailable.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)
(./check.aux)
No file check.bbl.

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 7.

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./check.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/
cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on check.pdf (1 page, 10912 bytes).
SyncTeX written on check.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on check.log.
```

Does anybody have an idea of how to fix this? I remind you that I am using TexShop. The bibliography is in the right folder and I have the latest version of Texshop.Thanks!!!!

I'll add here the bibliograpy:

```
@article{10.2307/2291464,
 ISSN = {01621459},
 URL = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/2291464},
 abstract = {I consider a standard specification of the Bayesian linear model and derive necessary and sufficient conditions for the variance of the case-deletion importance sampling weights to be finite. The conditions have an intuitive interpretation in terms of familiar frequentist measures of leverage and influence and are easy to verify. I present two real data examples in which the necessary conditions fail to hold for some observations and the corresponding importance sampling estimates are highly unreliable.},
 author = {Mario Peruggia},
 journal = {Journal of the American Statistical Association},
 number = {437},
 pages = {199--207},
 publisher = {[American Statistical Association, Taylor & Francis, Ltd.]},
 title = {On the Variability of Case-Deletion Importance Sampling Weights in the Bayesian Linear Model},
 volume = {92},
 year = {1997}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you run the normal cycle `(pdf)latex -> bibtex -> (pdf)latex (twice)`?

Comment: @Bernard Hi Bernard! usually when I run Codes on TexShop i just run the command TypeSet on the top left corner, and it compiles everything. Shall i do something different in this case?

Comment: This depends on what ‘Typeset’ is configured to do. I don'thave TeXshop at hand right now, but try to run `bibtex` on the file: it creats a `.bbl`file which is used on the following runs by LaTeX  to typeset the bibliography.

Comment: Your test document doesn't contain any `\cite` instructions.

Comment: As Bernard says, you need to run BibTeX. So a full compilation cycle would involved LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" can be your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...). https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 brilliantly explains what BibTeX does and why you need to run it. Some editors run exactly the command you tell it to run (if there is a button saying "pdfLaTeX" it runs pdfLaTeX once), some editors have a hard-coded sequence of commands that usually gives good results, some have heuristics to tell which commands to run. ...

Comment: ... Usually there will be  a way to explicitly run a bibliography tool like BibTeX/Biber. Note that in this example document you don't have a `\cite` or `\nocite` (or `\nocite{*}`) command, so there will be no citations and no entries in the bibliography (only works that were cited go into the bibliography; you can use `\nocite{<key>}` to add a work without citation output and `\nocite{*}` to add all works). So you probably want to try adding `\cite{10.2307/2291464}` in the test document and run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX again.

Comment: Last but not least, please keep in mind that you only have access to all `biblatex` features with (the default) `backend=biber,`. If you explicitly set `backend=bibtex,` you can only use a limited feature set. Consider changing `backend=bibtex,` to `backend=biber,` and running Biber instead of BibTeX. See for help with your editor https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. (Note that everything you have been told so far applies whether you use BibTeX or Biber: The principles are the same.)

Comment: @moewe. Thanks you all for the quick and especially clear answers. Putting together all your answers i was able to finally solve my problem! A HUGE THANKS to all of you.

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

As soon as I add a suitable `\cite` instruction to your test document and run it (from TeXshop version 4.44, on a Mac running MacOS 10.15.5 "Catalina" and MacTeX2020) through LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX once more, I get the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{check.bib}
@article{10.2307/2291464,
 ISSN = {01621459},
 URL = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/2291464},
 author = {Mario Peruggia},
 journal = {Journal of the American Statistical Association},
 number = {437},
 pages = {199--207},
 publisher = {[American Statistical Association, Taylor \& Francis, Ltd.]},
 title = {On the Variability of Case-Deletion Importance Sampling Weights in the Bayesian Linear Model},
 volume = {92},
 year = {1997}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{check.bib}
\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}
Ciao. \cite{10.2307/2291464}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, works the same for me!